# Numbers stripped of '$' and ',' won't convert from str to int

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, integer

I'm pretty new to Python, but am interested in taking tables, scraping them, and then running calculations. I took an income table from Wikipedia, stripped the columns with numbers of the dollar signs and commas (e.g. $26,400 to 26400) and then tried to convert them to integers and setting conditions based on the values. While the amounts show up without '$' or ',' in the updated dataframe, I still get an amount with '$' and ',' whenever I reference an individual entry *or* the columns.

Here's the code — apologies if I should have separated the blocks out more — it's my first post:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Maine_locations_by_per_capita_income"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

all_tables = soup.find_all('table', class_="wikitable")

A = []
B = []
C = []
D = []
E = []
F = []
G = []

for row in all_tables[0].findAll('tr'):
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    if len(cells) == 7:
        A.append(cells[0].text.strip())
        B.append(cells[1].text.strip())
        C.append(cells[2].text.strip())
        D.append(cells[3].text.strip())
        E.append(cells[4].text.strip())
        F.append(cells[5].text.strip())
        G.append(cells[6].text.strip())

df = pd.DataFrame(A,columns=['Rank'])
df['County']=B
df['Per capita income']=C
df['Median household income']=D
df['Median family income']=E
df['Population']=F
df['Number of households']=G

df
```

[The initial frame shows '$' and ','.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkyoh.png)

At this point, I stripped columns C through E of all '$' and ','s. Here's column C, as an example.

```
df['Per capita income'] = df['Per capita income'].str.replace(',', '')
df['Per capita income'] = df['Per capita income'].str.replace('$', '')
```

I then attempted to convert the values (sans commas and dollar signs) from "str" to "int".

```
df['Per capita income'] = df['Per capita income'].astype(int)
```

[The dollar sign and comma are gone, as seen below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVHgU.png)

While the change *displays* properly in the dataframe, any reference to any cell still yields a "str" with a dollar sign and comma.

[Argh!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLYlZ.png)

I'm assuming that I'm missing a step somewhere, because I've tried a few methods of converting "str" to "int."

Comment: You are making changes in `df['Per capita income']` not in `C`.

Comment: You can replace the symbols while creating your lists C to E like  `C.append(cells[2].text.strip().replace('$', ' ').replace(',', ' '))`

Comment: @baby_yoda Thank you for that, I modified the "append" commands to include those lines. It eliminated '$' and ',' but — even after trying to change the column from str to int — I still get "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'" when I try to subtract C[2] - C[4].

Comment: @shivank98 How would I modify my code to make the changes? I tried changing df['Per capita income'] to both df[C] and [C] but it didn't work.

Comment: Weirdly enough, print(df.dtypes) states that column C is an "int32" but I still cannot perform int operations on any of its values.

Comment: @Speedbird45B If if I am correct you want that when you print `c[4]` it give you `26983` without comma and `$`. right?

Comment: @shivank98 Correct, which I was able to do...the issue is that (once it had been stripped of comma and $) the values in the column wouldn't properly convert from str to int. The column is said to be "int32" but the values in the column (such as C[4] and C[2]) would still be "str" when I tried to add or subtract them.

Comment: @Speedbird45B I think `C.append(int(cells[2].text.strip().replace('$', ' ').replace(',', ' ')))` will do the work now values in C would be int.

Comment: @shivank98 It worked — thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work as per your doubts in comments.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Maine_locations_by_per_capita_income"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

all_tables = soup.find_all('table', class_="wikitable")

A = []
B = []
C = []
D = []
E = []
F = []
G = []

for row in all_tables[0].findAll('tr'):
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    if len(cells) == 7:
        A.append(cells[0].text.strip())
        B.append(cells[1].text.strip())
        C.append(int(cells[2].text.strip().replace('$', '').replace(',', '')))
        D.append(cells[3].text.strip())
        E.append(cells[4].text.strip())
        F.append(cells[5].text.strip())
        G.append(cells[6].text.strip())

df = pd.DataFrame(A,columns=['Rank'])
df['County']=B
df['Per capita income']=C
df['Median household income']=D
df['Median family income']=E
df['Population']=F
df['Number of households']=G

df
```